# Including my libraries without a full path

Tags: c++, cmake

The project has the following structure:

```
.
|- CMakeList.txt
`- src
   |- lib
   |  |- CMakeList.txt
   |  `- libA
   |     |- CMakeList.txt
   |     |- libA.c
   |     `- libA.h
   `- main
      |- CMakeList.txt
      `- main.c
```

and I want to include the `libA.h` file in `main.c` using `#include "libA.h"`, but an error occurs when trying to compile  `fatal error: hello.h: No such file or directory`. Can I make cmake add the appropriate include flags and I could write `#include "libA.h"`.

I understand that I can manually add flags like `-Ipath/to/src/lib/libA -Ipath/to/src/lib/libB ...`, but I would like to automate this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

If I create library

```
add_library(MyLib src/MyLib.cpp include/MyLib.h)
target_include_directories(MyLib PUBLIC include)
```

then I can write

```
add_executable(MyExe ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
target_link_libraries(MyExe MyLib)
```

The last line will automatically add the flag '-I/path/to/MyLib/include' when compiling `MyExe`.

Answer (score 0):

Include_directories should solve that for you:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html

Comment: I try use `set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")` and it worked. But `include_directories ("{CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in [`PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR.html) CMake variable to access the **root** source directory of your project. Use this with [`target_include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) to use `#include "libA.h"` in `main.c`:

In your `src/main/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable(MyMain main.c)
target_include_directories(MyMain PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/lib/libA)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to set your target_include_directories in your libA/CMakeLists.txt. After the target is built with add_library, you want to add the following instruction:

```
add_library(libA libA.c libA.h)
target_include_directories(libA PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

This instruction will specify that libA and any target that links to it also considers ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} as a path to look for includes. This is known as a library's public header. Ideally, you would want those header files to be in their own subdirectory so you could include them easily to your other projects, without having the libA.c file be in the include directory. For example:

```
.
|- CMakeList.txt
`- src
   |- lib
   |  |- CMakeList.txt
   |  `- libA
   |     |- CMakeList.txt
   |     |- include
   |     |  `-libA.h
   |     |- src
   |        `- libA.c
   `- main
      |- CMakeList.txt
      `- main.c
```